# Catkin: Use ROS message from another package

Tags: ros, catkin, messages, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I'm trying to use a ROS message defined in another package, lets say message_package in my own package which I will call myPackage. The problem I have is that catkin first tries to build *myPackage* **before** *message_package*. Hence I get a compilation error:

> fatal error: message_package/msg.h: No such file or directory
> `#include "message_package/msg.h"`

I don't understand why catkin does that. In the package.xml of myPackage I added

> `<build_depend> message_package </build_depend>`

and in the CMakeLists.txt I added

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> COMPONENTS
> roscpp
> std_msgs
> genmsg
> **message_package**  )

What else can I do to tell catkin to compile message_package BEFORE myPackage, so that the necessary headers are there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206257/catkin:-use-ros-message-from-another-package/) by [potAito](https://answers.ros.org/users/22025/potaito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martinerk0](https://answers.ros.org/users/65268/martinerk0/) on 2021-07-15**:
Why nobody upvotes question? :(   (I gave u upvote, thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add a build-time dependency between your package and the packages you depend on. Assuming the node you're trying to compile is called `your_executable`, try:

```
add_dependencies(your_executable ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [potAito](https://answers.ros.org/users/22025/potaito/) on 2015-03-30**:
Huh it's working, thanks. I thought that's taken care of with build_depend. What exactly is ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-03-31**:
It is a CMake variable containing all the targets exported by packages you depend on. See: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html for details.

**Comment by [potAito](https://answers.ros.org/users/22025/potaito/) on 2015-03-31**:
Aha! Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Mobeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/124998/mobeen/) on 2022-11-24**:
What will be your_executable ?

**Comment by [icore-az](https://answers.ros.org/users/82420/icore-az/) on 2022-12-14**:
name of your .cpp file. Example add_dependencies(ros_ssa_single_agent ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}) # Followed example https://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/